# Linear vs non-linear Correlation

Tags: correlation

How do i check that two random variables satisfy the requirements for computing correlation  via Pearson or Spearman? If the data is non-linear/ non-Monotonic, are there other tests i could use to compute a correlation coefficient?

Answer (score 1):

[Distance correlation](http://personal.bgsu.edu/~mrizzo/energy/AOS0283-reprint.pdf) takes also nonlinear correlations into account.

Comment: The link in your answer is not hyperlinking correctly. Please try putting triangle braces (`< >`) around it or putting space between the parenthesis and link.

Comment: It seems that the link is dead. :(